# How to use Data Annotations inheritance class

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I am using mysql and entity framework code first. I have a class `BaseEntity`

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int id { get; set; }


    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int siteId { get; set; }


    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public bool online { get; set; }


    [Column(Order = 6)]
    public bool deleted { get; set; }


    [Column(Order = 7)]
    public DateTime addDate { get; set; }


    [Column(Order = 8)]
    public DateTime updateDate { get; set; }


    [Column(Order = 9)]
    public DateTime deletedDate { get; set; }
}
```

and I have `Brand` which inherits from `BaseEntity`

```
 [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false,Inherited = true)]
public class Brand:BaseEntity
{
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string brandName { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public string brandLogo { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to build project there is an error:

```
Error   1   Attribute 'AttributeUsageAttribute' is only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute
```

I want to use data annotations for sorting columns. I want to see these columns in the database:

```
 1. id
 2. siteid
 3. brandName
 4. brandLogo
 5. online
 6. deleted
 7. addDate
 8. updateDate
 9. deletedDate
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Remove the `[AttributeUsageAttribute ....]` Your class is not an Attribute.

Comment: When I remove it, project is building but I wrote update-database, it is not sorting. How can I do this

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing test with this model/context

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, true) { }

    public DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }

}

public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int siteId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public bool online { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 6)]
    public bool deleted { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 7)]
    public DateTime addDate { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 8)]
    public DateTime updateDate { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 9)]
    public DateTime deletedDate { get; set; }
}

public class Brand : BaseEntity
{
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string brandName { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public string brandLogo { get; set; }
}

static class Test
{
    public static void Run(DbConnection connection)
    {
        using (TestContext db = new TestContext(connection))
        {
            db.Brands.Add(new Brand());
            db.SaveChanges(); // Just to run DB and Table creation statement
        }
    }
}
```

For sure you have to remove the AttributeUsageAttribute.
Using exactly your classes with EF 6.1.3 and SQL Server it works as expected (the table is created with the columns in the specified order).
I tried it using Microsoft Access Entity Framework provider (I can debug it and understand the behavior better because I wrote it) and it works.
So it seems a MySql Entity Framework provider bug

**BUT**
The EF providers should not decide the order of the columns. They should only do a foreach (I'm reading the Microsoft Access provider) and generate a creation string.
So a bug in this part of an EF provider is quite strange.

Wich version of EF are you using?